# Can't connect from bastion host to private instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bastion

I have a bastion host that I'm trying to use to SSH to a private instance. The instances are in different AZs (with different subnets). The VPC has a CIDR of 10.0.0.0/16. The bastion host subnet has the following route table

```
10.0.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0   <redacted internet gateway>
```

The private instance route table is

```
10.0.0.0/16 local
```

The ACLs for both subnets are wide open

```
100 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0    Allow
*   All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0    Deny
```

I've also fully opened the security groups for the private instance

```
sgr-03f51a67e52c85016   IPv4    All TCP TCP 0 - 65535   0.0.0.0/0
```

I can SSH to the bastion hsot, however any sort of connection attempt to the private instance fails with a timeout, including ping and ssh. Am I missing something here? I feel like everything is as open as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Dumb moment...I had no outbound rules set for the bastion security group. Opened the needed ports for outbound traffic and it's working appropriately.